# ASP.net / HTMLAgilityPack : Getting Value of span within div

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack

```
Dim myHtml As New HtmlWeb
    Dim myPage As HtmlDocument = myHtml.Load("http://www.mysite.com")
    Dim myNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode

    myNode = myPage.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='olpDivId']")
```

Inside of olpDivid there are there spans with identical classes

```
<span class="blah><a href="fsdfs1>1</a></span>
<span class="blah><a href="fsdfs1>2</a></span>
<span class="blah><a href="fsdfs1>3</a></span>
```

The problem is that inside of my olpDivId there are three spans with identical classes, and I need to get the text from inside the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
var myNode = myPage.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='olpDivId']/span[2]/a");

if (myNode != null)
{
    string value = myNode.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

I tested this code with the below html snippet

```
<div id="olpDivId">
    <span class="blah"><a href="fsdfs1">1</a></span> <span class="blah"><a href="fsdfs1">
        2</a></span> <span class="blah"><a href="fsdfs1">3</a></span>
</div>
```